# Hiding GUI elements dynamically using radio button in PySimpleGUIQt

Tags: python, user-interface, visible, invisible, pysimplegui

I used below approach from [this post](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/845) to hide GUI elements which works very well:

```
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg

layout = [          
         [sg.Checkbox('Module Selection', default = False, change_submits= True, key = '_checkbox1_', size=(15,1)),
         sg.Text('Module(.xlsx)', size = (15,0.5), auto_size_text = True, justification = 'right', key = '_moduletext_')]
         ]


window = sg.Window('A2L', layout, icon = u"icon\\index.ico", auto_size_buttons = False).Finalize()  
window.Element('_moduletext_').Update(visible = False) #makes the element invisible
values_dict={}


while True:  # Event Loop            
    button, values_dict = window.Read()

    if values_dict['_checkbox1_']:
        window.Element('_moduletext_').Update(visible = True)
```

The problem here is that If i replace the checkbox with a radio button then same code doesnt hide the gui element dyanmically.Below is the code with Radio button:

```
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg

layout = [          
             [sg.Radio('Module Selection','RADIO' default = False, enable_events = True, key = '_radio1_', size=(15,1)),
             sg.Text('Module(.xlsx)', size = (15,0.5), auto_size_text = True, justification = 'right', key = '_moduletext_')]
             ]


window = sg.Window('A2L', layout, icon = u"icon\\index.ico", auto_size_buttons = False).Finalize()  
window.Element('_moduletext_').Update(visible = False) #makes the element invisible
values_dict={}


while True:  # Event Loop            
        button, values_dict = window.Read()

        if values_dict['_radio1_']:
            window.Element('_moduletext_').Update(visible = True)
```

How to hide the element using Radio button in pysimpleGUIqt?

Comment: Radio Buttons usually have more than 1.  Unsure about the behavior of a single Radio.  A single Checkbox is fine, but not a radio button.

Comment: I think you've hit either a bug or the Radio Buttons enable_events isn't implemented.  I thought it was but may not be on Qt.  I'll make it a priority and look at the code.

Comment: @MikeyB I've just quoted you in [Is there a way for PySimpleGUI Radio Buttons to generate events when changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60846217/3904031)

Comment: Great.... these need to be asked on the GitHub.

Comment: This page literally has the answer to the other post you made and linked here.  The messages don't seem to be getting through.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling events for Radio Buttons was not implemented in PySimpleGUIQt yet.  Just finished the code for it and tried your code against it.

You need to download the [PySimpleGUIQt.py](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/PySimpleGUIQt/PySimpleGUIQt.py) file on the [project's GitHub site](http://www.PySimpleGUI.com) and place it in your application's folder.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. I got an error using your code which i explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034955/how-to-create-gui-from-the-pysimpleguiqt

Comment: I don't recommend posting these kinds of problems here.  Post them on the project's GitHub site.  You'll get quicker support and can more easily post your code and images.